# I'm trying to add a url to my Rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add a default url option and when I do I receive the following error message:

> unknown regexp option

I'm new to rails and not sure how to correct. Thanks!

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { https://rails-blank-robpb.c9user.io.com }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you forgot to add quotes.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'https://rails-blank-robpb.c9user.io.com' }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = 
{ 
  host: 'https://rails-blank-robpb.c9user.io.com'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a default host you need to pass the `:host` option as a configuration option:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { 
  host: 'https://rails-blank-robpb.c9user.io.com'
}
```

See section [Generating URLs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) of the `ActionMailer::Base` documentation for more information. To see a list of all available configurations check section Configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `protocol`, `host`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    host: 'rails-blank-robpb.c9user.io.com',
    protocol: :https
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around `https://rails-blank-robpb.c9user.io.com`

The reason why Rails throws an error is because ruby will try to evaluate regular expressions which are commonly store between forward slashes `/`

Check https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html for more information